# Clojure, I want Long multiplication to overflow

Tags: clojure, integer-overflow

I want to do 64 bit arithmetics (not natural numbers), so I e.g. need a multiplication of two longs to overflow silently.

```
(unchecked-multiply Long/MAX_VALUE 3)
```

does the trick. But

```
(def n Long/MAX_VALUE)
(unchecked-multiply n 3)
```

gives an overflow exception. What am I doing wrong?

(Clojure 1.5.1)

Comment: Have a look at * ' function.  (* ' n 3)

Comment: You want to get an overflow or you don't want to get it?

Comment: I want it to overflow, and to come out on the other side, so to speak. *' promotes to BigInteger, that is not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, both arguments are unboxed `long`s, so the `(long, long)` overload of `clojure.lang.Numbers.unchecked_multiply` is used. As expected, it does not throw on overflow.

In the second case, `n` is boxed, so the `(Object, Object)` overload is called, and that simply delegates to the `multiply` method which throws on overflow.

You need to say

```
(unchecked-multiply (long n) 3)
```

so that the `(long, long)` overload is used.

Comment: You are so fast, that I am allowed to accept your answer in 2 minutes only :-)

Comment: @Falko Cool, that's a nice bit of SO trivia -- I didn't know there was a time threshold. :-)